# Using the same backend for both mobile and web applications?

Tags: android, web

I want to develop an app which works for both web and mobile.I have developed an android app before using android studio. But this time i want to have the same backend for both mobile and web, so i decided to use nodejs for the back end and angular and react for the web front end. My question is what exactly do i need for this app to work on the android app as well? Will i need 2 back ends to develop my android app?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to achieve that

1) use a webview
if your web application is ready then you can plug your web interface and those application features into android app via [webview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView).

2) build a native android app using the existing REST API

when the API is ready you can call the routes from the app and then you can have data via http requests to the server. use some http libraries for android OKHTTP will be a better